# CSS - bottom border using :after pseudo-element that's the length of text

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have a `<h3>` that I need to style to contain a red bottom border behind it, using `::after` pseudo element.

**Goal:**
The red bottom border should only display the length of the text.

**Result:**
The closest I have it right now, the border spans the parent width.

[image: Border using CSS after pseudo]

```
<h3><span class="headingLine">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</span></h3>

span.headingLine:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 7px solid red;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; /* If I remove the width 100%, the red doesn't show */
  bottom: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**How do I adjust the markup / CSS so that the red border only spans the width of the text?**

*There may be instances of multiple lines of text (small browser window / lengthier heading)*

Comment: position:relative to span (and inline-block to it)

Comment: it already is inline-block. relative positioning pushes the red border below text, and it still spans full width of the parent.

Comment: inline-block to the span, not the after pseudo element and no it's not position:relative if I consider the figure you are showing unless you prove me wrong by posting your whole code

Comment: "to the span, not the after pseudo". Aha. Got it. Your solution works well with 1 line of text. 2 or more, and the red line only appears on the bottom-most line. (see the last part of my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is overcomplicated, just use a gradient background:

```css
h3 {
  border: solid 1px
}

span {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, red 6px, transparent 7px) 0 1.1em
}
```

```html
<h3><span class="headingLine">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</span></h3>
<h3><span class="headingLine">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Dolor Sit Amet Dolor Sit Amet Dolor Sit Amet Dolor Sit Amet Dolor Sit Amet</span></h3>
```

Comment: Very clean! I had to adjust the values a bit, but it's super close. Any way to push up that red line so it's more-so a background element? (in the screenshot I posted, the red line begins above the descender of the lowercase p)

Comment: @Joe, yes, it's adjustable. See background-position numbers.